# ExpressJS morgan log only route request

Tags: css, node.js, express

Im using NodeJS web framework Expressjs and one middleware to log requests to a file (morgan).

My conf:

```
// create a write stream (in append mode)
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/logs/access.log', {flags: 'a'})

// setup the logger
app.use(logger('short', {stream: accessLogStream}))
```

And my log looks like:

```
192.168.1.3 - GET /signup HTTP/1.1 304 - - 19.194 ms 
192.168.1.3 - GET /assets/css/admin/module.admin.stylesheet-complete.sidebar_type.collapse.no_min2.css HTTP/1.1 304 - - 15.500 ms 
192.168.1.3 - GET /assets/components/library/jquery/jquery.min.js?v=v1.0.3-rc2&amb;sv=v0.0.1.1 HTTP/1.1 304 - - 14.244 ms
```

Is there some way to ONLY log route request? for example if user enters /signup/:

```
192.168.1.3 - GET /signup HTTP/1.1 304 - - 19.194 ms
```

and not the assets required for the route.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Very surprised there is no API option for this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem, I've found simple solution, maybe it will help somebody. If you use express.static you can move this call above morgan call,
for example:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
...
app.use(logger('short'));
```

Static assets won't be logged. Notice: your assets files must exist, otherwise they will be still logged (tested in express 4.12).

Comment: wow, that was really simple and work as a charm. You the real MVP
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Static routes won't be logged if logger is instantiated after static routes

```
app.use(express.static('...')); // first declare static folder

app.use(logger('any format here')); // instantiate logger
```